# MySQL not using index on large WHERE IN clause

Tags: mysql, performance, index

I am trying to retrieve chunks of records from my table via a generated `SELECT WHERE IN` statement. If the statement is small, it will use the index, if the statement is large (1000+ IN items) it performs a full table scan. The table is 17 million rows long, so this gets expensive when I only want to look for 10k records.

I have a unique index covering (in this order) `date`, `world`, `player`, `city_id`. I also have an index for the date and player. The table is also partitioned by world.

**Example query:**

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE 
    (date, world, player, city_id) 
IN ( 
    ('2017-05-30',4,'player',15466761),
    ('2017-05-30',4,'player',567599046),
    ('2017-05-30',4,'player2',34567866),
    ('2017-05-30',4,'player',2342467),
    ('2017-05-30',4,'player3',92341268),
    ... etc
)
```

If the query is small, it will use the index, if the query is large it performs a full table scan. Even adding `FORCE INDEX (unique_index)` doesn't do anything for the large queries.

**Execution plan output:**

```
 "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "20928166.60"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "city_data",
      "partitions": [
        "w3",
        "w4",
        "w5",
        "w6",
        "w7"
      ],
      "access_type": "ALL",
      "possible_keys": [
        "unique_index"
      ],
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 17440138,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 8720069,
      "filtered": "50.00",
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "19184152.80",
        "eval_cost": "1744013.80",
        "prefix_cost": "20928166.60",
        "data_read_per_join": "3G"
      }
    }
```

**`SHOW CREATE TABLE` for `city_data`:**

```
CREATE TABLE `city_data` (
   `date` date NOT NULL,
   `world` int(3) NOT NULL,
   `player` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   `alliance` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `continent` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `castle` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
   `water` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
   `temple` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
   `x_coord` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `y_coord` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `city_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   `city_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
   `entry_id` int(55) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`,`world`),
   UNIQUE KEY `unique_index` (`date`,`world`,`player`,`city_id`) USING BTREE,
   KEY `world_index` (`world`) USING BTREE,
   KEY `date_index` (`date`) USING BTREE,
   KEY `player_index` (`player`(8))
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=17999069 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
 /*!50100 PARTITION BY LIST (`world`)
 (PARTITION w3 VALUES IN (3) ENGINE = MyISAM,
  PARTITION w4 VALUES IN (4) ENGINE = MyISAM,
  PARTITION w5 VALUES IN (5) ENGINE = MyISAM,
  PARTITION w6 VALUES IN (6) ENGINE = MyISAM,
  PARTITION w7 VALUES IN (7) ENGINE = MyISAM) */
```

How can I get it to use the index instead of relying on a full table scan?

I have read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586381/mysql-not-using-indexes-with-where-in-clause

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE city_data` .  Which version of MySQL?

Comment: Is the `IN` clause a list of constants?  Or a subquery like `IN ( SELECT ... )`?  It makes a _big_ difference.

Comment: @RickJames The `IN` clause is exactly as it's shown in my example. This is MySQL 5.7.18. I'm adding that now

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue with large `IN` clauses and `PARITIONing` -- Beyond some not-so-large-number, the Optimizer say "punt, I'll just send this query to every partition".  (This *may* be part of what you are seeing.)

But more than that.  Picking partitions is costly, not cheap.  If you end up with all the partitions, the query will be slower than if you did not have partitioning.  (I recommend removing partitioning.  I have found no use case where `BY LIST` helps performance.)

Most importantly...  "Tuples" are *not* optimized.  That is, the Optimizer does a terrible job with `WHERE (a,b) IN ((1,2), (3,4))`, regardless of the indexes.  Don't use it if you want performance.  (Or you could plead for the optimization feature at bugs.mysql.com).)  (This is the real answer to the question.)

So, what to do?  One approach is to create a temp table with all those tuples.  Then `JOIN` from that tmp table to the real table and have a composite index (as you have with `unique_index`) to make the lookups fast.

Some other notes.

- The number in `INT(55)` means nothing.  `INT` is always 4 bytes, with a range up to a few billion.  `world int(3)` should probably be `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (0..255) or `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (0..65535).
- "Prefix" indexing is rarely beneficial:  `KEY player_index (player(8)`); remove the `(8)`.
- `KEY date_index (date)` is redundant since there is another index (`unique_index)` starting with the same column.
- Recommend moving to InnoDB before MyISAM is deprecated.

Comment: Hey Rick, this may be important. I only ever need to use one partition at a time. ie. world 4, rarely if ever do queries use more than one world. In this case, I am using tuples since I need to find entries by the unique index from a web app, and rather than shooting off 10,000 separate queries, I would rather do it in chunks since the latency between the DB and the web server becomes the limiting factor when performing 1 query at a time. The actual use-case is checking to see if an item exists before attempting to insert, to avoid throwing unique index exceptions.

Comment: 3 statements (3 round trips) -- 1. `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...`; 2. `INSERT ...` with all the constants to look for; 3. `SELECT .. JOIN ..`

Comment: If most queries include `WHERE world=4`, then start some of the indexes with that column (after removing partitioning).  The optimal indexes are usually quite different with versus without partitioning.  _With_ partitioning, `world_index` is totally useless.

Comment: Gotcha, I will implement your suggestion for creating the temp table when I get home. Is partitioning pretty much useless then? This table will double in size every couple months, I was hoping to avoid full-table scans through partitioning, but my understanding of how partitioning works seems pretty poor.

Comment: A common misconception is that "partition is intrinsically beneficial".  My [_thoughts_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/partition-maintenance/).

Comment: Gotcha, thats a good read, thank you for sharing your knowledge. If you don't mind, could you expand on your suggestion to more to InnoDB from MyISAM in your answer? I am curious of the reasons, and it would be handy knowledge to have.

Comment: The next version after 5.8 is 8.0.  It is beginning to remove MyISAM from MySQL.  InnoDB has become better in virtually all aspects.  (There are a lot of blogs on such.)  My [_conversion tips_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb).  Hmmm... I should add to the rationale section.